# Make grub menu appear faster (not like an animation)

Tags: boot, grub2

I'm not sure if it's supposed to be that way or if it's a bug, but I'm forced to watch my Grub menu screen sloooooowly build itself. I have to watch it draw the lines around the menu like it was a C64 doing graphics and stuff. Takes about 5sec until I can finally see the menu entries and select one.

Any idea of how to get rid of that? I'm running Ubuntu Gnome 16.04, if it matters.

Comment: You probably have a Hi-Res screen. It is a challenge for Grub. ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved this by doing the following:

enter `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub` in terminal and edit/uncomment the line "GRUB_GFXMODE" so that it's `GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480`

Comment: Thanks. It's still not instant, but much faster. I set it to `800x600` though. I also had to run `update-grub2`.

Comment: You can see the possible resolutions for your computer at bootup: type `c` for command mode, then `vbeinfo`.

Comment: Rendering the menu at the native resolution took about 4 seconds. After setting `GRUB_GFXMODE=1024x768x8` the menu is rendered instantly. The last number indicates color depth (in bits).

Comment: "Asked 5 years, 6 months ago" - Oh, to be young again.